# Conversion Tracking in microsite

Tags: marketing-cloud, microsites, conversion

I have tried to replicate the conversion tracking that worked on the landing page to a microsite page. But somehow its not pulling the parameters from the url.

Link : https://www.example.com/j=JobID&sfmc_sub=SubscriberID&l=ListID&u=LinkID&mid=MemberID

(used the above format as the link for the microsite) Also tried using,

conversion="true" href="http://www.example.com/landing.php?"

used the below script code to get parameters from the url.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var urlParams;
  (window.onpopstate = function () {
    var match,
        pl     = /\+/g,  // Regex for replacing addition symbol with a space
        search = /([^&=]+)=?([^&]*)/g,
        decode = function (s) {
          return decodeURIComponent(s.replace(pl, " "));
        }
    ,
        query  = window.location.search.substring(1);
    urlParams = {
    };
    while (match = search.exec(query))
      urlParams[decode(match[1])] = decode(match[2]);
  }
  )();
  var xml = "";
</script>
```